# Eclipse - exception occured executing command line, No such file or directory

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, ubuntu, jvm

I recently came across a library that I needed to use, Jpcap, that requires a 32-bit JVM to run. After installing 32-bit Java on my machine running Ubuntu and configuring my application in Eclipse (Mars) to use that version of Java, I encountered the following error,

Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "/usr/lib/java/jre1.8.0_91/bin/java" (in directory "/home/[USERNAME]/EclipseWorkspace/[APPNAME]"): error=2, No such file or directory

I have verified that the path to the JRE directory is correct and that the java executable is present. Is there some configuration step that I'm missing? Does anyone have an idea of why Eclipse might not be able to get to that directory?

Comment: Take a look at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists

Comment: That thread hadn't come up in my searches. Thanks, this did the job.

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgot to update the JAVA_HOME environment variable. If that's the case you may want to follow this guide:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get

Basically you can use `sudo update-alternatives --config java` to get the java installation path and then edit, as su, the file `/etc/environment` adding or editing the field `JAVA_HOME="YOUR_PATH"`, where YOUR_PATH is the actual java installation path. At this point you can either restart your machine or just reload the environment variable by typing `source /etc/environment`.

Hope this helps!